# How to: Update (and allow changes to) drop-down menu based on incoming data

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a drop-down menu and set its value based on incoming data. I also want to be able to manipulate that value, and store it in a variable.

The data coming through is a bool.

This is how I imagined it would work, but not having much luck. I either get an error, or my value is wrong and I'm also unable to update it...

I have done something similar with a date picker and managed to get it to work, but struggling with this one...

```
String neuteredValue;
bool neuteredBool;
bool isInit;

@override
  void initState() {
    isInit = true;
    super.initState();
  }

//SCAFFOLD ETC

            Builder(
            builder: (ctx) {
              if (arguments.neutered != null && isInit == true) {
                neuteredBool = arguments.neutered;
              }
              if (neuteredBool == null) {
                neuteredValue = 'Unknown';
              } else if (neuteredBool == false) {
                neuteredValue = 'Unneuturerd';
              }
              neuteredValue = 'Neutered';
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text('Neutered?', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                value: neuteredValue,
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  isInit = false;
                  setState(() {
                    neuteredValue = newValue;
                    neuteredBool = !neuteredBool;

                    petData['neutered'] = neuteredBool;
                  });
                },
                items: <String>['Neutered', 'Unneutered ', 'Unknown']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          ),
```

Comment: use setState() to update DropdownButton value

Comment: Presumably you want to wrap `neuteredValue = 'Neutered';` in an `else` clause...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a Stateful Widget
2. Use a FutureBuilder for anything that is going to take some time(async)
3. Once the future resolves call setState()

**Example of a FutureBuilder**

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: futureBoolReady(),
  initialData: isReady,
  builder: (context, asyncBoolData) {
    if(!asyncBoolData.hasData) {
      return Text("Waiting For Data...");
    } else {
      return Text("$isReady");
    }
  })
```

**futureBoolReady()**

```
  Future<bool> futureBoolReady() async {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      setState(() {
        isReady = true;
      });
      return isReady;
    });
  }
```

As Ananta said, in your DropDown onChanged make sure to call setState() some where and assign your value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help and suggestions guys, I think I've solved it now

```
Builder(
            builder: (ctx) {
              if (arguments.neutered == null && isInit == true) {
                neuteredBool = neuteredBool;
                neuteredValue = 'Unknown';
              } else if (arguments.neutered == true && isInit == true) {
                neuteredBool = true;
                neuteredValue = 'Neutered';
              } else if (arguments.neutered == false && isInit == true) {
                neuteredBool = false;
                neuteredValue = 'Unneutered';
              }

              return DropdownButton<String>(
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text('Neutered?', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                value: neuteredValue,
                elevation: 16,
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  print(newValue);
                  isInit = false;
                  if (newValue == 'Neutered') {
                    setState(() {
                      neuteredBool = true;
                      neuteredValue = newValue;
                    });
                  } else if (newValue == 'Unneutered') {
                    setState(() {
                      neuteredBool = false;
                      neuteredValue = newValue;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      neuteredBool = null;
                      neuteredValue = newValue;
                    });
                  }
                },
                items: <String>['Neutered', 'Unneutered', 'Unknown']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            },
          ),
```